# Troubleshooting failed packer build

Tags: packer

I am just getting started with Packer, and have had several instances where my build is failing and I'd LOVE to log in to the box to investigate the cause.  However, there doesn't seem to be a `packer login` or similar command to give me a shell.  Instead, the run just terminates and tears down the box before I have a chance to investigate.

I know I can use the --debug flag to pause execution at each stage, but I'm curios if there is a way to just pause after a failed run (and prior to cleanup) and then runt he cleanup after my debugging is complete.

Thanks.

Comment: Tejay - Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I'm also wondering the same thing.

Comment: nope. I just use --debug.

Comment: yes - i also just use --debug. Does what you need, even though it's a bit tedious, and it could definitely be improved..

Answer (score 15):

This was my top annoyance with `packer`. Thankfully, `packer build` now has an option `-on-error` that gives you options.

`packer build -on-error=ask ...` to the rescue.

From the [packer build](https://www.packer.io/docs/commands/build.html#on-error-cleanup) docs:

> `-on-error=cleanup` (default), `-on-error=abort`, `-on-error=ask` - Selects what to do when the build fails. cleanup cleans up after the previous steps, deleting temporary files and virtual machines. abort exits without any cleanup, which might require the next build to use `-force`. `ask` presents a prompt and waits for you to decide to clean up, abort, or retry the failed step.

Answer (score 10):

Having used Packer extensively, the `-debug` flag is most helpful. Once the process is paused, you SSH to the box with the key (in the current dir) and figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the way I handle this is to put a long sleep in a script inline provisioner after the failing step, then I can ssh onto the box and see what's up. Certainly the debug flag is useful, but if you're running the packer build remotely (I do it on jenkins) you can't really sit there and hit the button.

I do try and run tests on all the stuff I'm packing outside of the build - using the Chef provisioner I've got kitchen tests all over everything before it gets packed. It's a royal pain to try and debug anything besides packer during a packer run.

Comment: Hi Ele, how can you ssh into the box without the --debug flag, which prints out connection details, passwords, and private keys, etc?

Answer (score 0):

While looking up info for this myself, I ran across numerous bug reports/feature requests for Packer.

Apparently, someone added new features to the virtualbox and vmware builders a year ago (https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/409), but it hasn't gotten merged into main.

In another bug (https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/1687), they were looking at adding additional features to --debug, but that seemed to stall out.

Answer (score 0):

If a Packer build is failing, first check where the build process has got stuck, but do the check in this sequence:

1. Are the boot commands the appropriate ones?
2. Is the preseed config OK?
3. If 1. and 2. are OK, then it means box has booted and the next to check  is the login: SSH keys, ports, ...
4. Finally any issues within the provisioning scripts

Answer (score 0):

The op did not mention the specific error.

In my case, the issue was "packer build..." hanging at "Waiting for SSH to become available" until it hit the 30-minute timeout (vs. hanging there for about the usual 8 minutes).

Changing from VirtualBox 7 to VirtualBox 6 allowed the build to complete.